# How to get loss functions on evaluation part from the following training procedure?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

So, I have followed this tutorial: https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#training-pipeline-conf and use it to make object detection. More specifically I detect cats. So, I have an image with cats and it finds them inside the image, and draws rectangles around them. The problem is that I am confused about the evaluation part. When I follow the procedure of evaluation, tensorboard displays images. The idea is that it shows me the **same** image twice, where on the left image, it has identified one cat, whereas on the right image it has identified all the cats, and shows me "step 12000". What I understand is that it takes the image at two different steps (for instance step:0, and step:12000) and shows me the progress. **Is that it?** Is there any better way to evaluate the objects, such as what it was required to detect and what the model finally detected? Far better: how can I take the loss functions on the evaluation period from the .pb model?

I have tried to search for an answer, such as here: https://manalelaidouni.github.io/Evaluating-Object-Detection-Models-Guide-to-Performance-Metrics.html but the procedure for evaluation is totally different..